# Error running Django tests

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev, django-testing, python-unittest

I'm trying to run Django tests ( version 1.8 )

But I get this error

```
from django.test import TestCase

class JobTypesResourceTest (TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        TestCase.setUp(self)
    def test_basicGet(self):
        return True

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309\pysrc\runfiles.py", line 234, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\user\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309\pysrc\runfiles.py", line 78, in main
    return pydev_runfiles.main(configuration)  # Note: still doesn't return a proper value.
  File "C:\Users\user\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309\pysrc\pydev_runfiles.py", line 835, in main
    PydevTestRunner(configuration).run_tests()
  File "C:\Users\user\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309\pysrc\pydev_runfiles.py", line 793, in run_tests
    MyDjangoTestSuiteRunner(run_tests).run_tests([])
  File "C:\Users\user\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309\pysrc\pydev_runfiles.py", line 813, in run_tests
    raise AssertionError("Unable to run suite with DjangoTestSuiteRunner because it couldn't be imported.")
AssertionError: Unable to run suite with DjangoTestSuiteRunner because it couldn't be imported.
```

Am I missing a python library ?

Comment: Your code contains a typo: not `true`, but `True`

Comment: Thanks I already fixed it so that's not the issue

Comment: Your test class works for me. Do you have a traceback?

Comment: Hi I have used the default file hierarchy that you get when you create a new Django project, and I am running using Eclipse run as pyunit

Comment: It looks like you should configure Pyunit test runner. Better not to use an IDE though. :-°

Comment: Thanks i will try and run it using manage.py

Comment: @soon Can you please tell me the exact command you used to run the tests ?

Comment: @WilletteLynch, just `manage.py test` as described in the documentation

Comment: This is the output that I get. It says it didnt run any tests
`python manage.py test --keepdb
Using existing test database for alias 'default'...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Preserving test database for alias 'default'...`

Answer (score 2):

Don't use context menu 'Run as' -> 'Python unit-test'. Use project's context menu 'Django' -> 'Run Django Tests (manage.py test)' instead.

To create launch configuration for Django Tests copy launch configuration that runs your Django project (automatically created after 'Run as' -> 'PyDev: Django')
and change program arguments from 'runserver' to 'test'.

Answer (score 1):

Your `TEST_RUNNER` setting is set to `django.test.simple.DjangoTestSuiteRunner` or a subclass of it.

`django.test.simple.DjangoTestSuiteRunner` was [deprecated in Django 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/1.6/#discovery-of-tests-in-any-test-module) and [removed in Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/1.8/#features-removed-in-1-8).

Since you are using Eclipse, I think [this](http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_pyunit.html#configuring-test-runners) is accurate for you.

Comment: I have made no changes to Django 1.8, as you can see the only code I have used is what I have written above, So I have written no code that uses the DjangoTestSuiteRunner

Comment: What is your `TEST_RUNNER` setting set to? (if set) Please provide the full traceback, as @soon said.

Comment: I have not set the test runner, And have added the stack trace

Comment: You didn't, but your IDE did. You have to configure it to use the right test runner.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the help. Looks like I was running the tests wrong. I was using Eclipse-> run as pyunit option which looks like was using older code. Was working when I ran using `manage.py test`